# Gitlab api to revoke authorized applications

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm following this link https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/oauth2.html#web-application-flow to use Oauth2 to authorize application.

I succeed to get the access_token and access gitlab resource on user's behalf. But I cannot find any document to revoke it programmatically. Is this supported?

Comment: It doesn't appear so. The only way I can find on how to revoke an access token is to do that through the GitLab GUI. I don't think it can be done through the API, for example.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html

Comment: @IsaacAbramowitz thanks. seems still a long way to go for gitlab.