# Is it (now) possible to revoke Gitlab access tokens through the API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, gitlab, revoke-token

Two years ago, someone asked if it was possible to [programmatically revoke access tokens through the Gitlab API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438620/gitlab-api-to-revoke-authorized-applications). The answer then was no. I have not located recent information confirming or rejecting that this is still true.

I was hoping to use something like this with Python's http request library:

```
 headers = {'Authorization':  clientSecret}
 res = gitlab.post("https://gitlab.com/oauth/revoke", headers=headers, data={
            'client_id': clientID,
            'access_token': accessToken
        })
print(res.text)
```

However, the response has been empty with different variations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In light of information [here](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-revoke-gitlab-authorize-token/51645), it seems completely possible to revoke the access tokens.
This works:

```
 payload = {"token": accessToken,
            "token_type_hint": "refresh_token"
        }
 auth = HTTPBasicAuth(clientID, clientSecret)
 res = requests.post("https://gitlab.com/oauth/revoke",
                    data=payload,
                    auth=auth,
                    )
```

Comment: it's ok to accept your own answer :)